# Linting - Code analysis for bugs, errors and style issues in the Wolfram Language

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure we already have something similar, but I'm working on more code inspections for the IntelliJ plugin and it's always a good idea to ask the community. Since it doesn't really fit on main, I'm posting it here on Meta.

Linting is an excellent way to point the developer to probable errors that he might have overlooked. With a dynamic language like the one of Mathematica, we are a bit restricted with what we can do, since we cannot evaluate code and since most things require evaluation to be sure if they are a bug or not. Nevertheless, there are checks we can do. For instance `If[a=b, ..]` is most likely a bug and even if the developer knew what he did, it is a bad style.

There are trickier examples like `If[a<5,...]`. This looks okay but knowing that `a<5` stays unevaluated if the comparison cannot be done, it is a source of error because you end up with the unevaluated `If` expression in your wrong result and debugging might be complicated.

In both examples, wrapping `TrueQ` around the condition resolves the issue and although there might still be a bug, at least you can be sure your `If` expression is evaluated to some branch.
Other common sources of error are, e.g. `x_?testFunc[#]&` or implicit multiplication through linebreaks.

**Question:** What are common bugs in your code and could they have been pointed out by a linter? If you like to share your thoughts, please provide one issue per answer, so that others can vote. I'm looking forward to your suggestions and see if I can implement some of them in IntelliJ.

---

Example issue: With the [alternative layout for packages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/176489/187) which was pointed out by Leonid, we can use *directives* for a static code analyzer to easily export symbols or declare them as package symbols. As Leonid pointed out, the directives need to be on their own source-line with nothing else on it. So for the directives

```
PackageScope["myFunc"]
PackageExport["MyExportedFunc"]
```

I implemented the following rules

1. They need to be on their own source line with nothing else on it
2. Their string argument must be a valid identifier

[image]

Comment: I can't really think of any off the top of my head, but one thing worth contemplating is whether it is necessary to *only* include bugs or whether it's also worth adding best-practices suggestions (like making sure each a `::usage` message starts with the name of the symbol it's being defined for or something)

Comment: @b3m2a1 I actually have tests in my test suite to verify that each usage message starts with the name of the symbol that it belongs to. It would indeed be useful for the IDE to check this.

Comment: @Szabolcs yeah I thought of it because I *never* do it and am always like like "wow I should really be doing this..."

Comment: Are lower case Symbol names for trig functions and `sqrt` detected?  These seem to slip in out of habit for even non-novice *Mathematica* users from what I have observed.

Comment: How about this? `posVec_List ? AllTrue[Positive]`  The intention is to write a pattern for a vector containing all positive numbers. But `?` actually binds even tighter than `[ ... ]`! It must be written as `posVec_List ? (AllTrue[Positive])`. I do not fall for `x_?testFunc[#]&` anymore but I did fall for this one a few times.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The plugin already does that because it tries to resolve all used symbols (http://i.imgur.com/SlGvVRC.png). So if you haven't defined `sqrt` yourself, then this will always trigger a warning.

Comment: @Szabolcs Should be a small fix on the existing inspection.

Comment: Another small idea: warn about nested pure functions with `Slot`-arguments, like `#^2& /@ Join[#,#]&`.  Many people would prefer to turn such an inspection off, and even those of us who strive to never write such code might rarely benefit from it (as it's relatively easy to avoid doing this).  It might be useful when refactoring others' code (I think @Kuba does that a lot). I'd suggest low priority if you consider it at all.

Comment: I need to leave now but we might find good tips in Fateman's original criticism paper:  https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~fateman/papers/mma.review.pdf

Answer (score 13):

> ## Status Partially Completed

### 1. Invalid number of arguments for some of built-in functions e.g.

- `Which` called with an odd number of arguments
- `Switch` called with an even number of arguments
- `Module/With/...` called with more than two arguments

  I don't think it needs to work for every built-in function but will probably be useful for scoping and conditional expressions.

### 2. Backtick in `Begin` and friends

- `Begin` called with `` "Private`" `` instead of `` "`Private`" ``

  etc.

---

**Implemented**

[image: img]

---

Oh, I almost forgot my personal number one problem:

### 3. `ClearAll @ foo`

when it is called after options/attributes or any definition for `foo` was defined.

### 4. Need for explicit `Optional`.

This gives a syntax error, it is debatable but certainly can be unexpected:

```
    {_} : {1}
```

Comment: Excellent suggestions. I already thought about 1. more than once and although I have the information for most built-in functions, I believe it would be too annoying to the experienced developer to see such warnings when arguments are regularly zipped together with `Sequence`, `##`, `With`, and whatnot.. For a selected set of scoping functions, this makes sense though. The backtick bug is also nice, but when someone *wants* to begin a context without leading backtick, he cannot get rid of the warning except turning the whole inspection off. I have to think about that.

Comment: The last example is nice, but it requires to resolve all definitions for `foo` before the `ClearAll` which might be too slow for a fast local inspection. On the other hand, there are usually not so many `ClearAll` in package code and this might be worth a shot.

Comment: @halirutan 1. If you can detect and ignore cases with `##` then I think it should be done. Dealing with With injecting sequences is probably too tough. At the end MMA allows to much freedom with respect to syntax to care about such cases. User can disable this feature or it can be disabled by default if needed. 2. Only for hardcoded ``"Private`"`` then, 95% chance it was a mistake.  3. I'd say ClearAll should not be present inside implementation part, it happens for me because I deal a lot with others code so I sometimes forget to remove it. ...

Comment: @halirutan ... It should be a best practice to only ``ClearAll["`*", "`*`*]`` on top and every other case should be flagged. Again, user can disable this.

Answer (score 10):

> ## Status Completed

It would be neat if IntelliJ could detect this precedence issue:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, ColorFunction -> Hue[#3] &]
```

it should be

```
Plot3D[Sin[x y], {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, ColorFunction -> (Hue[#3] &)]
```

This may not be as much of a problem in an IDE as in a notebook, but nevertheless:

```
{1, 2, 3}/.2 -> 3
```

There is a missing space between `/.` and `2`.

### Comment halirutan:

Excellent suggestions and I implemented both. Anonymous function in IntelliJ are *italic* and it is easier to see the scope, but I included this inspection anyway

[image: function]

The second inspection has some corner-cases, but a basic version is also available now

[image: replace]

Answer (score 5):

These are really common mistakes that go unnoticed because they are valid syntax:

- `Which` statement using `_` as the final predicate
- `Switch` statement using `True` as the final pattern
- A list with a random dot product in the middle, usually means someone typed a period instead of a comma in a long multi-line list

Comment: The `Which` one screws me over daily...

Answer (score 4):

> ## Status Completed

I agree with @CE that precedence issues would be great to point out, and maybe suggest to the programmer to use more parentheses. The relative precedences of `@`, `@@`, `@@@`, `/@`, `/.`, `//.`, etc. and the scopes of any associated slot operators `#`, `##`, etc. are sometimes difficult to track; can't expect anyone to remember the full [Operator Precedence Table](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html). I tend to use the CTRL-. selection trick to group-select according to precedence (that would also be great if you don't yet have it in IntelliJ); but complex cases still exceed my mental capacity.

For example, quick, without looking it up, does

```
f /@ {1, 2, 3} /. i_ -> i^2
```

give `{f[1]^2, f[2]^2, f[3]^2}` or `{f[1], f[4], f[9]}`? In my opinion such edge cases deserve a lint warning.

### Comment halirutan:

As said in the comment, structure-based selection already worked for a long time and you can hit `Ctrl`+`W` to expand or `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`W` to shrink the selection

[image: img]

For highly complex expressions, rather than making a warning message which probably would annoy experienced users, maybe a "Can you parenthesize this expression for me"-action would be more convenient. With this, the user can quickly check how an expression is parsed

[image]

This feature is now integrated into the plugin. When you are editing a file and want to quickly see the parenthesitation (if this is a word), you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>. This will put your file in read-only mode and display all parenthesis. Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> brings you back to edit-mode.

Note:

- The shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> is really just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>(</kbd> on US layouts, which should make it easy to remember
- You can also use the menu entry **Wolfram Language | Show Parentheses**

Comment: Yes, IntelliJ also has structure based selection of expression. The algorithm for computing some kind of *operator complexity measure* is too time-consuming for a "local inspection", but something like that can be implemented as global inspection which is not run after each key-stroke. I *believe* it should not be too hard to implement, but I need to think about this some more. However, you gave me another great idea and I need to read some IntelliJ code to see if I can make this work.

Comment: @halirutan - if you could make that work it would be fantastic. That is one of the only reasons I still use `Eclipse`, that I can keep clicking an expression and the selection expands based on scope.

Comment: @JasonB. The structure-based selection worked almost from the beginning of the development years ago (https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0bcU.gif). The difference is that it is bound to `Ctrl`+`W` for increasing and `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`W` for decreasing the selection. The repeated click has a standard meaning in idea: First select token unter the cursor, then select the whole line.

Answer (score 4):

> ## Status Completed

I often accidentally include a `;` at the end of a line in the variable declaration for `Module/Block/DynamicModule/etc` or screw them up somehow. It'd be nice if IntelliJ could catch fundamental, silly errors like that.

E.g. I do this all the time:

```
Module[{a, b, c; d=10, f, 12},  
  ...
  ]
```

And presumably both of those would be pretty easy to do for the IDE

**Comment halirutan:** I have implemented this. Here you see 3 warnings

[image: img]

The first warning on `a` is because it is not used inside the `Module` body. The other two warnings are because it is not a valid variable declaration or assignment.

This will be published in **version 2019.1.2**

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this qualifies as a separate claim related to operator precedence. I include it as an answer simply to facilitate the discussion format, even though I believe it should be a comment, instead.

I consistently have had a hard time with `expr//f/*g` when `g` is an anonymous function (ie defined '*then and there*' like eg `f/*#^2&`). The issue becomes more complicated when *more* functions are involved or when the complexity of the functions involved, increases.

A close second, which is probably too idiosyncratic or personal, has to do with confusing `Options` with `Attributes` and using `SetOptions` (like one would have used `SetAttributes`) when defining new functions. Obviously, using `SetOptions` instead of `Options` on a symbol that has no default `Options` causes a `SetOptions::optnf` message.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you mean by "I consistently have had a hard time"? Do you mean that the anonymous function also captures the `f/*` part, right?

Comment: yes, I keep *consistently* forgetting that when I intend eg. `x//f/*#^2&` to evaluate to `f[x]^2` I need to use parentheses as in `x//f/*(#^2&)` because `&` binds tighter than `/*`.

Answer (score 2):

> ## Status Partially Completed

### Unused variables

```
fun[x_, y_] := x^2

        ^ y is unused
```

```
Module[{x, y},  <-- y is unused
  x+1
]
```

```
y=1;  <-- this instance of y is effectively unused
y=2;
```

The last one is quite involved and may be difficult to implement, therefore I won't give more examples of this type unless you ask.

Generally, the idea is that if a localized variable (`Module`, `Block`, `With` or function arg) is unreferenced within the local scope, there should be a warning.

Cases to exclude:

- `Rule`, as it is typically used with explicit pattern matching, where naming subpatterns often aids readability even if their value isn't used.
- Patterns like `fun[list : {x_, x_}] := ...` where a subpattern needed to be named to indicate repetition.

**UPDATE:**

It may be best to add this for `Module` and `With` only for the time being. `Block` has too many reasonable uses where the localized variables do not need to appear explicitly, e.g. `Block[{$RecursionLimit = ...}, ...]` or setting other flags which are user-defined, but affect the Block body in a similar way.

---

**UPDATE 2:**

The Workbench has this feature:

[image]

**Comment halirutan:** This inspection has been implemented and is available since WL Plugin version 2019.1

Answer (score 2):

> ## Status Completed

### Invalid attributes

The Workbench has a feature where it will warn about invalid attributes in constructs similar to

```
Attributes[symbol] = {attr1, attr2, ...};
```

[image]

It does not at this point warn about wrong attributes in `SetAttributes` though.

I think this would be a useful inspection because it is not an uncommon mistake to try to use `Hold` instead of `HoldAll`, or `HoldComplete` instead of `HoldAllComplete`.

This should *not* be of high priority because:

- `Attributes[foo] = ...` will typically appear at the top level and get evaluated at package load time.
- Mathematica will show an error message when trying to set a wrong attribute.

Thus this error won't go unnoticed for long even if the IDE doesn't warn about it.

---

**Comment halirutan:** I have implemented this

[image: img]

It will be available in the WL Plugin **version 2019.1.2**

Answer (score 2):

> ## Status Completed

I'll convert my comment as this came up again:

This is already handled:

```
_?foo[#]&
```

But with the many operator forms, now this is a common mistake:

```
_?foo[12]
```

For example,

```
f[x_?GreaterEqualThan[5]] := Sqrt[x-5]
```

IDEA should warn about this.

**Comment halirutan:** Very good catch! I fixed this and it should now also report such operator forms

[image: img]

Will be available in WL Plugin **version 2019.1.2**

Answer (score 1):

### Non-ASCII characters

Add an inspection to warn about non-ASCII characters that appear anywhere else except in comments.

The encoding that Mathematica will assume when loading a file using `Get` is not predictable and typically differs between operating systems. E.g., on macOS/Linux it might assume UTF-8 while on Windows it may assume Windows-1252.  If the source file contains anything but ASCII, it might be interpreted differently on different platforms.

Such characters will typically appear in strings such as usage messages.  I personally encountered this:

https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/issues/44

I used non-ASCII characters in my usage messages when I edited the source files on macOS and on Windows they appeared as Chinese characters.

*Note:* I would exempt comments from this inspection because misinterpretation won't usually cause problems there. In principle it could, in particular if it affects the closing `*)` (note that in my example above an extra ASCII letter was corrupted), but usually it won't.  I expect many people will want to write comments in their native language.

**Comment halirutan:** I've implemented this and created a mapping to all known named characters so that I can provide a QuickFix which is able to replace the Unicode character automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Things like

```
f[a_Association]:=...
```

Should ask if you want to convert to

```
f[a_Association?AssociationQ]:=...
```

And similarly

```
f[a_?AssociationQ]:=...
```

Should ask if you want to do the same

The longer pattern is the fastest, most robust one, for most pattern types:

```
f[a_Association?AssociationQ] := True;
g[a_?AssociationQ] := True;
h[a_Association] := True;

a = Association[1];
b = <||>;
c = Dogs;

RepeatedTiming[f[a];, 1] // First
RepeatedTiming[f[b];, 1] // First
RepeatedTiming[f[c];, 1] // First

1.2*10^-6

1.2*10^-6

4.7*10^-7

RepeatedTiming[g[a];, 1] // First
RepeatedTiming[g[b];, 1] // First
RepeatedTiming[g[c];, 1] // First

1.2*10^-6

1.2*10^-6

9.3*10^-7

RepeatedTiming[h[a];, 1] // First
RepeatedTiming[h[b];, 1] // First
RepeatedTiming[h[c];, 1] // First

7.2*10^-7

6.9*10^-7

4.3*10^-7
```